# Unable to call a procedure even after granting execute on it

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

`call dev02.copy('A','B')` gives ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.
The `copy` is a procedure defined in the Oracle database's `dev02` schema,
and I have executed the `grant execute on dev02.copy to dev08`.
I am running the call statement on the `dev08` schema.
Since the grant execute is provided on the dev02 procedure.
I am not sure what could be going wrong. The procedure is a default definer's right one.
Any ideas on how to debug or figure this out?

Under the ORA-00942 error there is also one more error `ORA-06512`: at ... line 46  Sounds like there is some issue at this line of the procedure
**Things I tried:**
I found that I am getting the same error even if I call the procedure from dev02 which is owned by dev02 but when I modified the procedure with invoker's right by adding the line `authid current_user` it works on the dev02

Comment: Oracle provides also a line where the error occurs in addition to ORA-942, so you can easily find what statement failed. Or you can use `alter session set events '942 trace name ERRORSTACK level 3'; ` to dump a full errorstack with all failed statements into the trace file

Comment: The error is about tables either not existing or not being visible at runtime; it isn't the privileges on the procedure itself. it would help to show a [mre] - if your procedure is too long to post them create a cut-down one that demonstrates the problem. I would guess that you're using dynamic SQL since it's a runtime error, and you're trying to copy data from table A to tables B? If so which schema are those in, and do you specify that schema in the code? And do both users have privs on them - and directly or via roles?